How close can I put deck footings together?
Getting ready to drill out deck footings for free standing 16*16 deck near house. I'm unable to use ledger board on this house. My electrical line runs right through the middle of the deck. I read not to dig within 24” of electrical line. Inspector said to put footing 2 ft from house. That so that takes away 6 ft of space to place footers. Plan calls for 4 footers in the line. Best space I can find to put them is ~3.5 ft apart on 1 side with a 6ft gap in the other. The other option is to have two placed 2 ft apart.

It would help if you drew a rough plan.

I can't wrap my head around your design or math. Please post pics of the area you plan to build in and a sketch of the planed deck with the electric line marked as well.

Is the E-line parallel to the house, or perpendicular?
